# Bounty expiration notices missing from inbox on Android

Tags: bug, bounties, notifications, android-app

A few minutes ago, my inbox count (number on a red background at the top right) showed 1 in the Android app, but 3 on the desktop site. Dragging down in the main page didn't change the number.

In the Android app, I got to read one comment notification.

On the desktop site, I also had two bounty expiration notices (1-day-left warning). These aren't appearing in the Android app.

Bug: bounty expiration notices aren't reaching (or reaching through) the Android app.

Comment: In fairness, you can't *place* bounties either

Comment: @mhlester So? It's still useful to have the expiration notice: “quick, go find a browser!”

Comment: I agree. It *should* tell you. And I'm surprised it doesn't. I would have figured it's the same inbox API as the desktop. Which got me wondering if they explicitly disabled bounty notices

Comment: yes I had the same problem, highly frustrating!

Comment: @mhlester weird... the [/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) API method doesn't have the bounty expiration notice there (I just got one on the web version, so it should be there on the API, but it isn't)... :/ Not sure how the web version makes the notification then..?